# Keypress count on blurred window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count users' keypress while web app opened. Although, I cannot detect it while the window is not active.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    let i = 0;
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
        i++;
    alert( i );
    });
});
```

Comment: If the window isn't active how can the user give an input for you to detect?

Comment: That would be a security desaster.

Comment: Isn't there a way to detect it?

Comment: You can't detect keystrokes when the input is not your webpage, if that's what you're asking